what are your music recommendations for someone trying to expand their music taste?
i want to expand my music taste so tell me ur fav albums!! i’m open to any genre as long as it’s good music. adding more characters because this dumb site wants me to for some reason…

Recommendations are outside the scope of the forum

What should I keep out of my posts and titles? Also, if you don't want nerds to answer your question, you're in the wrong place.

Start with completely different music that you likely aren't used to. If you mostly listen to pop and rap music, try listening to more schooled music. Bands like Tool use odd time signatures and have deep messages in their songs. Their use of vocabulary in their lyrics is incredible. Bands like Dream Theater are very schooled musicians who create rock music on a level that most people cannot fathom. If you have never listed to Jazz, and I mean never sat down and spent time exploring Jazz music, you should do that. Do that with anything you have never explored.

Deloused in the Comatorium, by The Mars Volta/Aenima by Tool/Lateralus by Tool/Dummy by Portishead/Fat of the Land by The Prodigy/Appetite for Destruction by Guns n Roses/Toxicity by System of a Down/Pork Soda by Primus/Sailing the Seas of Cheese by Primus/ The Downward Spiral by NIN...That should keep you busy for a while..hope you enjoy these recommendations...more to come.

Only under specific circumstances are multiple answers allowed here. You can simply [edit] your contributions to add or remove things. But, again, this question is off-topic, and you really need to add reasons for your recommendations.

Tres Hombres by Zz Top/Rated R by Queens of the Stone Age/Leave Home by the Chemical Brothers/Disintegration by The Cure/Fugazi/Bad Brains/The Crow Soundtrack/Tori Amos/Fiona Apple/The Pixies/Paul's Boutique by Beastie Boys/Led Zeppelin 4/Coza Frenzy by Bassnectar

Hi Nathan, a good answer would explain why these are good recommendations. The question is off-topic here, and will (some day) get deleted, but it's still good to have a look in the [Help] for more informationon writing proper answers. Welcome!

Keep in mind it takes some time and attention to get to know a new style of music, especially if it's very different from what you've heard before, so don't expect to like or understand everything right away. Don't dismiss it just because it sounds boring, or dissonant, or mumbly, or dumb, or too intellectual or whatever.
With that in mind, here are some of the strategies that have expanded my musical tastes:

Ask people I respect for recommendations: A lot of music I initially hated, I grew to love because people I respected loved it. XTC, Tom Waits, Ewan McColl, Billie Holliday, Bob Dylan, Bjork, Nina Simone--they are all amazing artists that were initially opaque to me because they challenge the listener, but that I persisted with because someone close to me thought they were worth it.
Radio/playlists: I'm not a big fan of the algorithm, or of big corporate radio, but if you can find an indie, college or public radio station that still plays individual tastes, you can still encounter a lot of great music that way. Same on streaming services. Don't let the algorithm spoonfeed you, look for curated playlists by interesting people. People used to make each other mixtapes--first real, then CD, then virtual. That's how I found The Magnetic Fields.
Record stores: Whether or not you collect vinyl, record stores are still the best place to find dedicated music nerds who live and breathe everything from dusty classics to the newest cutting edge tracks. That's how I found Os Mutantes, maybe the most revelatory band ever. Watch the movie High Fidelity if you haven't. Speaking of which:
Soundtracks: Next time you hear a great song on a show or in a movie, hunt it down. I've never been a true hip hop head, but I did a deep dive on Wu Tang after watching their excellent Hulu series. Reservation Dogs brought me some great songs, from "Look at What the Light Did Now" to "Come and Get Your Love." I also did a lot of downloads from Insecureand Dear White People. And "New Slang" from Garden State "changed my life."
Deep Cuts: They're especially hard to find, these days, when people are less likely to buy albums, but next time you hear a golden hit, see what else that person has done. Sinead O'Connor is a lot more that "Nothing Compares 2 U." The Temptations sang more than just "My Girl." Like Frank Ocean said on Sweet Life "The best song wasn't the single..." Speaking of which...
Crews: Who is your favorite artist's favorite artist? Or their protege? Who is in their crew? If you start from Janelle Monae, you can end up at St Beauty. Frank Ocean can lead you to Tyler, the Creator. From the Beatles, you can find Billy Preston. From Outkast, you can get to Killer Mike or the Goodie Mob. Goodie Mob takes you to Gnarls Barkley, and from there to Broken Bells, and now you're back at the Shins again.
Time Travel: Different eras have really different music. How about a little Frank Sinatra (40s)? Some Bill Withers (70s)? Simon & Garfunkel (60s)? Dave Brubeck Quartet (50s)? Prince (80s)? Lead Belly (30s)?
Go International: I'm not just talking British invasion. Is there a little Bob Marley and Jimmy Cliff in your collection? How about Tinariwen? Miriam Makeba? Kraftwerk? Gilberto Gil?

If all else fails, just listen to the Gorillaz.
